# Login/register web service

Tags: services

I am creating a web service for login and register, but I want a single URL for register and login so that, when a user registers, it will automatically log in. No need for two services for register and login.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user gets saved in DB using user_save() it returns the user object. All you have to pass it to $GLOBAL['user']; and save session

```
   //Here is your previous code I assume where you have user_save()

   $user = user_save($userData);

   if($user) {
        drupal_save_session(FALSE);      
        $GLOBALS['user'] = $user;
        drupal_save_session(TRUE);
   }
```

Hope this may help you